# awk / gawk printf when variable format string, changing zero to dash

Tags: awk, printf

I have a table of numbers I am printing in awk using `printf`.
The `printf` accomplishes some truncation for the numbers.

```
(cat <<E\OF
Name,Where,Grade
Bob,Sydney,75.12
Sue,Sydney,65.2475
George,Sydney,84.6
Jack,Sydney,35
Amy,Sydney,
EOF
)|gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
FNR==1 {print("Name","Where","Grade");next}
{if ($3<50) {$3=0}
printf("%s,%s,%d \n",$1,$2,$3)}'
```

This produces:

```
Name Where Grade
Bob,Sydney,75 
Sue,Sydney,65 
George,Sydney,84 
Jack,Sydney,0 
Amy,Sydney,0
```

What I want is to display scores which are less than 50, or missing, as a dash ("-").

```
Name Where Grade
Bob,Sydney,75 
Sue,Sydney,65 
George,Sydney,84 
Jack,Sydney,- 
Amy,Sydney,-
```

This requires the 3rd string format in  `printf` change from %d to %s.
So in some rows, the third column should be a value, and in some rows, the third column should be a string.  How can I tell this to GAWK?  Or should I just pipe through another awk to re-format?

Comment: please add some sample input and show expected output for that sample.. it'd help in understanding your question better and allow answerers to test their solution...

Comment: The only thing that's clear so far is - whatever it is you're trying to do, no, you should **not** pipe through another awk to re-format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
FNR==1 {print("Name","Where","Grade");next}
{if ($3<50) {$3="-"} else {$3=sprintf("%d", $3)}
printf("%s,%s,%s \n",$1,$2,$3)}' ip.txt
Name Where Grade
Bob,Sydney,75 
Sue,Sydney,65 
George,Sydney,84 
Jack,Sydney,- 
Amy,Sydney,-
```

- use if-else to assign value to `$3` as needed
- `sprintf` allows to assign result of formatting to a variable

  - for this case, you could use `int` function as well
- now `printf` will have `%s` for `$3` as well

Assuming you missed the commas for the header and space after third column is not needed, you could do this with a simple one-liner

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR>1{$3 = $3 < 50 ? "-" : int($3)} 1' ip.txt
Name,Where,Grade
Bob,Sydney,75
Sue,Sydney,65
George,Sydney,84
Jack,Sydney,-
Amy,Sydney,-
```

- `?:` ternary operator is alternate for if-else
- `1` is an awk idiom to print contents of `$0`

Comment: `^1` for the second script. Obviously you would not use the first one!

Comment: @Sundeep "Assuming you missed...".  Correct :)